# Added tab completion to JFileChooser's File Name inputer

Tags: java, linux, swing, jfilechooser, tab-completion

How can I add linux like tab completion to jFileChooser's File Name input field?  I'm assuming I need to add a listener to the File Name's text input box to listen for the tab key.  But I don't know how to do that.  Then once a tab key is hit, I need to look at the directory for files/dir that start with what was inputted.  Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I am not pretty sure what the question is but if you want to control is the textfield does contain a file name or something you can simply use JFileChooser as a panel and, as I may remember, there is a way to show/not show its components like "open"/"save"/etc buttons and, of course, replace them with your own; so there should be a way to control its input field I guess. So you need to play around UIManager

For more information you can read [this](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0507/hill/index.html) , [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0569.html) and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LocalizeaJFileChooser.htm)

If it is not the point... so I still hope you configure your question in a more detailed manner because it is quite unclear :)

Good luck